# Difficulty reading .txt data when running Stable Marriage algorithm in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying to execute the code below regarding Stable Marrage algorithm, but when executing the code below you get the following error:

> Error: For input string: "3 " Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   br.com.entrada.GaleShapley.(GaleShapley.java:21)  at
>   br.com.entrada.GaleShapley.main(GaleShapley.java:166)

Gale Shapley Marriage Algorithm

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GaleShapley
{
private int N, engagedCount;
private String[][] menPref;
private String[][] womenPref;
private String[] men;
private String[] women;
private String[] womenPartner;
private boolean[] menEngaged;

/** Constructor **/
public GaleShapley(String[] m, String[] w, String[][] mp, String[][] wp)
{
    N = mp.length;
    engagedCount = 0;
    men = m;
    women = w;
    menPref = mp;
    womenPref = wp;
    menEngaged = new boolean[N];
    womenPartner = new String[N];
    calcMatches();
}
/** function to calculate all matches **/
private void calcMatches()
{
    while (engagedCount < N)
    {
        int free;
        for (free = 0; free < N; free++)
            if (!menEngaged[free])
                break;

        for (int i = 0; i < N && !menEngaged[free]; i++)
        {
            int index = womenIndexOf(menPref[free][i]);
            if (womenPartner[index] == null)
            {
                womenPartner[index] = men[free];
                menEngaged[free] = true;
                engagedCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                String currentPartner = womenPartner[index];
                if (morePreference(currentPartner, men[free], index))
                {
                    womenPartner[index] = men[free];
                    menEngaged[free] = true;
                    menEngaged[menIndexOf(currentPartner)] = false;

                }
            }
        }            
    }
    printCouples();
}
/** function to check if women prefers new partner over old assigned partner **/
private boolean morePreference(String curPartner, String newPartner, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (womenPref[index][i].equals(newPartner))
            return true;
        if (womenPref[index][i].equals(curPartner))
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
/** get men index **/
private int menIndexOf(String str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (men[i].equals(str))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
/** get women index **/
private int womenIndexOf(String str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (women[i].equals(str))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
/** print couples **/
public void printCouples()
{
    System.out.println("Couples are : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(womenPartner[i] +" "+ women[i]);
    }
}
/** main function **/
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Gale Shapley Marriage Algorithm\n");
    /** list of men **/
    String[] m = {"1", "2", "3"};
    /** list of women **/
    String[] w = {"1", "2", "3"};

    /** men preference **/


    String[][] mp = null ;
    /** women preference **/                      
    String[][] wp= null ;

 // Input.txt is like
 // 3 <--defines the size of array
 // male preference array
 // 1 3 2
 // 1 2 3
 // 2 3 1

//female preference array
//1 3 2
//2 1 3
//2 1 3


    try{
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;
      int line=0;
      int k=0;
      int n=0;
      int i=0;
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
         if(line==0){
            n =Integer.valueOf(strLine);
            mp=new String[n][n];
            wp=new String[n][n];
            line++;
         }
         else{

             String[] preferences=strLine.split(" ");

             if(i<n){
                 mp[i]=preferences;
             }
             else{
                 wp[i-n]=preferences;
             }
             i++;
         }
      }
      in.close();

        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    GaleShapley gs = new GaleShapley(m, w, mp, wp);                        
   }
  }
```

The program is not reading the input.txt input file completely. It is reading only the first line of this file. And I can't solve this. I think the problem should be in the code part below.

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
         if(line==0){
            n =Integer.valueOf(strLine);
            mp=new String[n][n];
            wp=new String[n][n];
            line++;
         }
         else{

             String[] preferences=strLine.split(" ");

             if(i<n){
                 mp[i]=preferences;
             }
             else{
                 wp[i-n]=preferences;
             }
             i++;
         }
      }
```

Below is the input file: input.txt

```
3 
male preference array
1 3 2
1 2 3
2 3 1

female preference array
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 1 3
```

Comment: It looks like `mp` is `null` in `new GaleShapley(m, w, mp, wp)`

Comment: And real problem is obscured because `System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());` is not printing a stacktrace which will tell you what exception was thrown and where.

Comment: As @StephenC said it has to be mp.length that causing an exception.First try to check the file input.txt from which you are assigning values to the variable mp.I feel the code is not calling the mp = new String[n][n];.it may be because your file is empty.

Comment: I got the same error when i copied and pasted the code into my ide. Wrap your code in if (new File("input.txt").exists()) {} as i suspect you're not reading the file

Comment: it is reading only the first line of input.txt.

Comment: Compiler says that your problem located in the 21th line where your assign a String array `m` to the object `men`, i.e. `men = m;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is thrown due this : `3` => it contains a **whitespace**
  And when you call the `Integer.parse(N)`, `N` cannot be parsed to `Integer` while there's this **whitespaces**,

To resolve this, i used   `strLine.trim();`

> **women[i].equals(str)** : you are comparing here a string to an Integer is always `false` and the result of your function `womenIndexOf` is -1, and this is going to throw an exception of **IndexOutOfBounds** Exception when using the -1 as index

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GaleShapley {
    private int N, engagedCount;
    private String[][] menPref;
    private String[][] womenPref;
    private String[] men;
    private String[] women;
    private String[] womenPartner;
    private boolean[] menEngaged;

    /** Constructor **/
    public GaleShapley() {

    }

    public GaleShapley(String[] m, String[] w, String[][] mp, String[][] wp) {
        N = mp.length;
        engagedCount = 0;
        men = m;
        women = w;
        menPref = mp;
        womenPref = wp;
        menEngaged = new boolean[N];
        womenPartner = new String[N];
        calcMatches();
    }

    /** function to calculate all matches **/
    private void calcMatches() {
        while (engagedCount < N) {
            int free;
            for (free = 0; free < N; free++)
                if (!menEngaged[free])
                    break;

            for (int i = 0; i < N && !menEngaged[free]; i++) {
                int index = womenIndexOf(menPref[free][i]);
                if (womenPartner[index] == null) {
                    womenPartner[index] = men[free];
                    menEngaged[free] = true;
                    engagedCount++;
                } else {
                    String currentPartner = womenPartner[index];
                    if (morePreference(currentPartner, men[free], index)) {
                        womenPartner[index] = men[free];
                        menEngaged[free] = true;
                        menEngaged[menIndexOf(currentPartner)] = false;

                    }
                    engagedCount++;

                }

            }
        }
        printCouples();
    }

    /** function to check if women prefers new partner over old assigned partner **/
    private boolean morePreference(String curPartner, String newPartner, int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (womenPref[index][i].equals(newPartner))
                return true;
            if (womenPref[index][i].equals(curPartner))
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** get men index **/
    private int menIndexOf(String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if (men[i].equals(str))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    /** get women index **/
    private int womenIndexOf(String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (women[i].equals(str))
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    /** print couples **/
    public void printCouples() {
        System.out.println("Couples are : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println(womenPartner[i] + " " + women[i]);
        }
    }

    /** main function **/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Gale Shapley Marriage Algorithm\n");
        /** list of men **/
        String[] m = { "1", "2", "3" };
        /** list of women **/
        String[] w = { "1", "2", "3" };

        /** men preference **/

        String[][] mp = null;
        /** women preference **/
        String[][] wp = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Youssef\\Projects\\STS\\TEST\\src\\input");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            int line = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line == 0) {
                    n = Integer.valueOf(strLine.trim());
                    mp = new String[n][n];
                    wp = new String[n][n];
                    line++;
                } else {
                    if (strLine != null && !strLine.equals("") && !strLine.contains("male")
                            && !strLine.contains("female")) {
                        String[] preferences = strLine.split(" ");

                        if (i < n) {
                            mp[i] = preferences;
                        } else {
                            if (i - n < w.length) {
                                wp[i - n] = preferences;

                            }
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                }
            }
            in.close();

            new GaleShapley(m, w, mp, wp);

        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand, but I still don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Invoke method `trim()` to `strline` before its casting to int: `n = Integer.valueOf(strLine.trim());`

Comment: I understand, but I still don't know how to solve "women[i].equals(str)" within the code.

Comment: The error still appears.  "Error: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3". How to solve this problem?

Comment: women[i].equals(str): You are comparing a string to a number, the str value has a string number and the check fails, that's why you are getting a -1 returned and when you pass it to the array -1 index is going to throw an ArrayOutOfBounds Exception

Comment: Don't miss that the readLine() is reading also this => 'male preference array'

Comment: @RobertoMonteiro check the code now, i don't know what the result should looks like but i add some checks to avoid exceptions

Comment: I suggest you to use ArrayList instead of using primitive arrays

Comment: I was able to execute @Youssef Tounoussi code. However, there is a line that comes out null.

Comment: Gale Shapley Marriage Algorithm

Couples are : 
1 1
2 2
null 3

Comment: Yes,  my code result is : 1 1 2 2 null 3, as i said i solved only programmatic issues, and not business logic, could you please tell me what the result should looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Follows the code running below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GaleShapley
{
    private int N, engagedCount;
    private String[][] menPref;
    private String[][] womenPref;
    private String[] men;
    private String[] women;
    private String[] womenPartner;
    private boolean[] menEngaged;


    public GaleShapley() {}

    /** Constructor **/
    public GaleShapley(String[] m, String[] w, String[][] mp, String[][] wp)
    {
        N = mp.length;
        engagedCount = 0;
        men = m;
        women = w;
        menPref = mp;
        womenPref = wp;
        menEngaged = new boolean[N];
        womenPartner = new String[N];
        calcMatches();
    }
    /** function to calculate all matches **/
    private void calcMatches()
    {
        while (engagedCount < N)
        {
            int free;
            for (free = 0; free < N; free++)
                if (!menEngaged[free])
                    break;

            for (int i = 0; i < N && !menEngaged[free]; i++)
            {
                int index = womenIndexOf(menPref[free][i]);
                if (womenPartner[index] == null)
                {
                    womenPartner[index] = men[free];
                    menEngaged[free] = true;
                    engagedCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    String currentPartner = womenPartner[index];
                    if (morePreference(currentPartner, men[free], index))
                    {
                        womenPartner[index] = men[free];
                        menEngaged[free] = true;
                        menEngaged[menIndexOf(currentPartner)] = false;
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
        printCouples();
    }
    /** function to check if women prefers new partner over old assigned partner **/
    private boolean morePreference(String curPartner, String newPartner, int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (womenPref[index][i].equals(newPartner))
                return true;
            if (womenPref[index][i].equals(curPartner))
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /** get men index **/
    private int menIndexOf(String str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if (men[i].equals(str))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
    /** get women index **/
    private int womenIndexOf(String str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if (women[i].equals(str))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
    /** print couples **/
    public void printCouples()
    {
        System.out.println("Couples are : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(womenPartner[i] +" "+ women[i]);
        }
    }


    /** main function **/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Gale Shapley Marriage Algorithm\n");
        /** list of men **/
        String[] m = { "1", "2", "3" };
        /** list of women **/
        String[] w = { "1", "2", "3" };

        /** men preference **/

        String[][] mp = null;
        /** women preference **/
        String[][] wp = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("src\\input.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            int line = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line == 0) {
                    n = Integer.valueOf(strLine.trim());
                    mp = new String[n][n];
                    wp = new String[n][n];
                    line++;
                } else {
                    if (strLine != null && !strLine.equals("") && !strLine.contains("male")
                            && !strLine.contains("female")) {
                        String[] preferences = strLine.split(" ");

                        if (i < n) {
                            mp[i] = preferences;
                        } else {
                            if (i - n < w.length) {
                                wp[i - n] = preferences;

                            }
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                }
            }
            in.close();

            new GaleShapley(m, w, mp, wp);

        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

The result is:

```
Gale Shapley Marriage Algorithm

Couples are : 
1 1
2 2
3 3
```